# In AngularJS how to get the new index of an array element after sorting?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

This snippet shows my problem nicely:

[JSfiddle - sorting table](http://jsfiddle.net/wEBnX/)

Important parts:

```
<tr ng-repeat="result in results | orderBy:predicate" ng-class="classRow($index)">

$scope.classRow = function(i) {
    return $scope.results[i].size > 9000 ? 'highlight' : '';
}
```

As you can see, the index always goes from 0 to 6 even when re-sorting the array, so the highlight doesn't move with the item.

How can I get the highlight to stick to the item it's originally at?

Comment: one thing to realize about `$index` within `ng-repeat` filtered or sorted items, is not the original array index. For example if filter takes 10 items and cuts them in half, new `$indexes` will be `0-4` regardless of what original array indexes are. `$index` will be index of new filtered or sorted array used internally by angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also do this inline, so there's no need for controller code:

```html
ng-class="{ highlight: result.size > 9000 }"
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/wEBnX/2/

Comment: Thanks for the good answers, Josh and @jszobody. Choosing this one for elegance.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than working off of an index, pass in the size property directly to `classRow()`.

```
<tr ng-repeat="result in results | orderBy:predicate" ng-class="classRow(result.size)">

$scope.classRow = function(size) {
    return size > 9000 ? 'highlight' : '';
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/WqbNS/